# SFSafariViewController opens rather than native Facebook app for "login with Facebook"

Tags: ios, facebook, safari, ios9

I am integrating `login with Facebook` functionality in my app. Before `iOS 9` it works like charm.

**Before:** If device has native facebook app installed and login, then `login with Facebook` button opens native app otherwise opens safari browser.

**Now:**
If device has native facebook app installed and login, then `login with Facebook` button opens `SFSafariViewController` in app.

I have updated facebook sdk to 4.7 (latest),

**Update:**  How should i disable `SFSafariViewController` from opening and open native app for login (if native app is available.)
please help me what to do now. Thanks in Advanced

Comment: its the latset SDK function of facebook

Comment: Yes. Today i have updated facebook SDK

Comment: as per apple documents , not redirect to ouside the app, so facebook has integrated this type of pages in new sdk

Comment: if it is correct, then what is the use of native facebook app. If user has already login to native app then also user has to login every time from safari browser for specific app.

Comment: for security purpose it is implemented,

Comment: Do you have any documentation link from apple?

Comment: see this link https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2015/08/17/SDK-for-iOS9/

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Thanks, that gives clean idea.

Answer (score 1):

In your Info.plist under the LSApplicationQueriesSchemes key (an array of strings):

[image]

Then... In you login button add the next line:

```
  FBSDKLoginButton * facebookLoginButton =[[FBSDKLoginButton alloc] init];
  facebookLoginButton.loginBehavior=FBSDKLoginBehaviorNative;
```

If you use custom button you also can add it to the FBSDKLoginManager class like that:

```
  FBSDKLoginManager * fbManager =  [FBSDKLoginManager new];
  fbManager.loginBehavior=FBSDKLoginBehaviorNative;
```